# How to autoscroll the scrollView horizontally?

Tags: ios, swift, autoscroll

I am using this code to scroll the scrollview horizontally when sliding the scrollview.

```
func getScrollView() {
        upperScroll.delegate = self
        upperScroll.isPagingEnabled = true
        //        pageControll.numberOfPages = logoImage.count
        upperScroll.isScrollEnabled = true

        let scrollWidth: Int = Int(self.view.frame.width)

        upperScroll.contentSize = CGSize(width: CGFloat(scrollWidth), height:(self.upperScroll.frame.height))
        print(upperScroll.frame.size.width)
        upperScroll.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        for index in 0..<logoImage.count {
            let xPosition = self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(index)
            upperScroll.layoutIfNeeded()
            let img = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(xPosition), y: 0, width: upperScroll.frame.size.width, height: self.upperScroll.frame.height))
            img.layoutIfNeeded()
            let str = logoImage[index]
            let url = URL(string: str)

            img.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: UIImage(named:"vbo_logo2.png"))
            upperScroll.addSubview(img)
        }
        view.addSubview(upperScroll)
        upperScroll.contentSize = CGSize(width: CGFloat((scrollWidth) * logoImage.count), height: self.upperScroll.frame.height)
    }
```

But i want to auto scroll? 
How can i do this. Can anyone help me please.

Comment: When you say autoscroll, you mean to a particular point in the scrollview?

Comment: i want at a particular time it scroll automatic like after 10 seconds? @AatishMolasi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the solution

```
@objc func animateScrollView() {
        let scrollWidth = upperScroll.bounds.width
        let currentXOffset = upperScroll.contentOffset.x

        let lastXPos = currentXOffset + scrollWidth
        if lastXPos != upperScroll.contentSize.width {
            print("Scroll")
            upperScroll.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: lastXPos, y: 0), animated: true)
        }
        else {
            print("Scroll to start")
            upperScroll.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), animated: true)
        }
    }

func scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(){
        // Scheduling timer to Call the function "updateCounting" with the interval of 1 seconds
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10, target: self, selector: #selector(self.animateScrollView), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
```

and call this function in ViewDidAppear

Comment: Good job. I added advanced(by: ) after .width and played around with the timeInterval and now I have it sliding nicely

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619400-setcontentoffset?language=objc

```
func scrollToPoint(point: CGPoint) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(10.0)) {
        upperScroll.setContentOffset(point/* where you want to scroll to*/, animated:true)
    }
}
```

you can specify the x axis when you are creating the point to pass to the func:
   `CGPoint(x: 100, y: 0)`

Comment: even if you use `upperScroll.setContentOffset(point/* where you want to scroll to*/, animated:true)` alone?

Answer (score 0):

There are method available to scroll for visible `rect` in `scrollView`. You need to pass `CGRect` in method, this means area where you want to scroll.

```
- (void)scrollRectToVisible:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about that:

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: (#selector(ViewController.timerAction)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true) 

@objc func timerAction() {
        var xOffSet = 0
        xOffSet += 10
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: {
            self.scrollView.contentOffset.x = xOffSet
        }, completion: nil)
    }
```

[How to implement auto scroll in UIScrollview using Swift 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44585590/how-to-implement-auto-scroll-in-uiscrollview-using-swift-3?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: where we will call timer.fire() @Kowboj

Comment: viewDidLoad? wherever you want it to start

Comment: [_SwiftValue timerAction]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000065fce0'
i am getting this error when i have written this in viewdidload

Comment: Don't use .fire(), sorry. Just put it in viewDidLoad, and add "ViewController." there:
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: (#selector(ViewController.timerAction)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)