# Automatic scroll an constant velocity in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiscrollview

I have a page where I would like to have a scrollview scroll at constant velocity. This appears very frequently in guitar websites, where the page basically autoscrolls.
For example, on [this](https://www.chords-and-tabs.net/song/name/bruno-mars-when-i-was-your-man) site, you could click where it says "autoscroll", and you could use a slider to adjust the autoscrolling speed. I was wondering if you could do that in UIKit or even better, in SwiftUI. I know there's the `ScrollViewReader`, but that is mainly used to jump to a location.

It would be great if anyone could give me some kind of guidance on this, Thanks!

Comment: Probably a better fit for UIScrollView or NSScrollView

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of UIScrollView and then wrap it in a UIViewRepresentable. However, I still do not know how to implement this logic. There seems to be a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49974662/how-to-autoscroll-the-scrollview-horizontally 
but I don't know how to utilize that scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval method

Answer (score 0):

`scroll.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: xPos, y: yPos), animated: true)`